# Game Engine as EXE and Game as DLL?

Tags: dll, exe, game-engine

Hi guys I'm starting the design of a new little game engine and I was assuming the game engine as a DLL and then build a project for the game that would use this DLL and output an EXE file.

But then I read about the latest ID Tech Game Engines and how they do it the other way around. (http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/index.php)

It's not really explained why though. I have the feeling it has something to do with modding as only the Game (DLL in this case) was open to the public for quite some time while the Engine (EXE) was closed source.

But I would like to know if there are other reasons for this.

As fas as I know the DLL project should have all the reusable code. The normal project should be the application, which would reference the reusable DLL. This way you can build a framework in the DLL project that can be used for any of other future projects.

The other only reason I can think of is that AFAIK only the name of the DLL is recorded in the program file, no text or data so if the Game is potentially bigger than the Engine, it could make the executable size smaller.

[EDIT]

I have thought of another reason to have it this way: The Engine is an EXE so it could be that it could be used without a Game DLL? Like for tools such as CAD or scripting?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a library in an application e.g. a game, then you have an app with an EXE with zero or more of its own DLLs consuming a library with one or more DLLs.

If you have a generic environment loading elements that customize it's  behavior, thus making it a specific game, then you have an environment with an EXE and zero or more DLLs which uses configuration to load various DLLs and configuration files to determine its behaviour.

Either easy, you should probably have more than two assemblies in your application.

E.g. one (the EXE) for loading the main config and modules and connecting them all, one for the main UI, one for the graphics, one for the physics, one for the AI and etc.

Comment: Yes, I do know that. For example "3d game engine programming" by Stefan Zerbst delves into the use of a different DLL for each module. But it has the game as the central piece that holds everything together. That is why I ask if there is a hidden reason for having the Engine (in the case of IDTech4 "Engine" is everything except the graphics module which goes in a different DLL) be the central part (EXE file) and load the Game as a DLL.

Comment: Building a generic game environment that turning into a specific game depending on modules and config is levels beyond writing a game that uses other modules and can not be easily reused for other games.

Comment: Could you put an example? I believe you could achieve the same generic game environment using modules.

Comment: Look up composite application architecture.